# foreachRDD not accepting JavaRDD<String> as return type

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

When I am trying to give JavaRDD as second argument to new Function() instead of Void.

```
stream.foreachRDD( new Function<JavaRDD<String>,JavaRDD<String> >() {

public JavaRDD<String> call(JavaRDD<String> inputRDD) throws Exception {
// do some stuff
}
return RDD
}
```

Below error I am getting:

> The method foreachRDD(Function,Void>) in the type AbstractJavaDStreamLike,JavaRDD> is not applicable for the arguments (new Function,JavaRDD>(){})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreachRDD` function on a DStream requires a method that does not return a value.  Specifically, it must implement the [`VoidFunction` interface](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/VoidFunction.html).

The goal of `foreachRDD` is to perform an action with a batch of data from the stream, such as persisting it to a permanent store or publishing it to a display.  I'm not entirely sure what you're looking to do, but if you're looking to mutate the RDD in any way, this is not the right method for you.